# How to register my Flutter app to open Zip files on iOS (Open with ...)

Tags: ios, flutter

(Would like to also know the solution for Android, but iOS is the top priority)

Hi there,

I wonder if there's a minimal example to show how to open Zip file with my Flutter app (e.g. On iOS, I have a zip file in mail attachments, and I use "Open with ... (my app)" to open that one and do some custom logic.

I already changed the `info.plist` file to register my app in the iOS list. However when it navigates to / launches my app, I don't know how to continue to process that file.

I guess there can be anything like "launch options" in Flutter's `runApp` function? Any clue is welcomed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [uni_link](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) package to archive this.

For **IOS** you have to modify your `Info.plist` accordingly:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.pkware.zip-archive</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Where:

- **CFBundleTypeRole** is the role of this app. The value can be Editor, Viewer, Shell, or None. This key is required.
- **LSHandlerRank** – How ios is specify this app against similar applications. Possible values: “Owner”, “Alternate”, “Default”, “None”
- **LSItemContentTypes** is a list of supported content. UTIs is iOS data format that use instead of mime type. List of UTIs you can find [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html).

For **Android** you have to modify your `AndroidManifest.xml` accordingly:

```
<manifest ...>
<application ...>
    <activity ...>
        <intent-filter >
            <action android_name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android_name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android_mimeType="application/zip" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Where:

- **android_mimeType** is mime type of supported types. List you can [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types).

And finally in your flutter app:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:uni_links/uni_links.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show PlatformException;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
   Future<void> initUniLinks() async {
     try{
        final initialLink = await getInitialUri();
        // TODO handle link here
     } on PlatformException {
       // TODO handle exception here
     }
   }

    unawaited(initUniLinks());
    return MaterialApp(
        home: ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, when I use "CFBundleURLTypes" in `info.plist`, I cannot see my app in the "open with..." list anymore (unlike using "CFBundleDocumentTypes"). Is it expected? (iOS 16)

Comment: Just noticed that I can simply add a section of `CFBundleDocumentTypes` in addition to the answer and everything works magically!