# How to add 'open with' option of my flutter App (Android)?

Tags: java, android, flutter, pdf, share

Search a lot but couldn't find satisfactory answer! [Want to add my Apps option here] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOT3p.png)

A Small example app would really help.

Added  in Manifest file but still not getting option, after this incoming intend is needed to be handled.

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74081875/13541839

Basically, you can specify what type of files your app handles in `AndroidManifest.xml`

I think it's better to refer to android specific documentation for this issue: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.